# boundary not working to find particular keyword in a paragraph

Tags: java, regex, string, word-boundary

I want to find a particular word out of a paragraph. I used boundaries to find one. Consider the following example.

```
String para = "Hi how are you. I'm harshita. Hello. Hell. Helld, Hell,";
String keyword = "Hell";
boolean matches = var.matches(".*\\b"+keyword+\\b.*");
System.out.println(matches);
```

This code gives me the following error when I run it on my unix server.

> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 5
>   .*\bTMTH_EQUIP_IDLE_REASON\b.*
>         ^
>         at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
>         at java.util.regex.Pattern.escape(Pattern.java:2177)
>         at java.util.regex.Pattern.atom(Pattern.java:1952)
>         at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1834)
>         at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1752)
>         at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1460)
>         at java.util.regex.Pattern.(Pattern.java:1133)
>         at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:823)
>         at java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(Pattern.java:928)
>         at java.lang.String.matches(String.java:2091)
>         at com.acc.directory.scanner.SDScanner.main(SDScanner.java:309)

I tried replacing `\\b` with `\\\\b`  but it didn't work. It returns false.
Can anyone please help me how should I resolve this problem. I searched everywhere but gives me just one answer to replace `\\b` with `\\\\b` but it is not working for me.

PS. It is just a dummy example to show what i tried and what output I want. I ran my code with real data and the error is taken from that output.

Comment: Looks like you forgot the quote: `boolean matches = var.matches(".*\\b"+keyword+"\\b.*");`

Comment: Please check the quotes in line 3. What is `var`?

Comment: sorry, I made the mistake while posting the question. But In my code those things are proper. Kindly guide me on using boundaries.

Comment: Your exception message does not match the code given. Please provide an SSCCE http://sscce.org/

Comment: It is just an example to show what I am trying to do. I have complex data which I have to run on unix server. There I am getting this kind of error. So I wanted to know how to resolve it

Comment: Try using `var.matches(".*\\b"+Pattern.quote(keyword)+"\\b.*");`. Does it work now? If not, you should explain what `keywords` you pass. If the keyword does not start or end with a word character (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`), this regex will never find a match then. A real life example would be really helpful.

Comment: Which Unix exactly? What Java version do you have on Unix?

Comment: @thomas Its 1.6 both for my code and the unix .

Comment: @stribizhev the keywords have starting character as string. In between it may have some special characer. For example: General_Ledger.

Comment: Why are you fooling around with it ? Use a known simple regex with a boundary `\b` that matches, something like `"\\bH"`. If it doesn't work, the problem is not with the regex, its something else.

Comment: @HARSHITASETHI: Just a not: the underscore is a *word* character, too.

Comment: @HARSHITASETHI: Have you still got any issues or is your question answered? If not, try `boolean matches = para.matches(".*(?<!\\w)"+Pattern.quote(keyword)+"(?!\\w).*");`

Comment: Or `boolean matches = para.matches(".*(?<![^\\W_])"+Pattern.quote(keyword)+"(?![^\\W_]).*");` to include matching between `_`.

Comment: Just an idea: if the issue with the backslashes persists, try quadrupling them: `boolean matches = para.matches(".*\\\\b"+keyword+"\\\\b.*");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the matches function against `para` variable and also you forget to put `"` before the second `\\b`

```
String para = "Hi how are you. I'm harshita. Hello. Hell. Helld, Hell,";
String keyword = "Hell";
boolean matches = para.matches(".*\\b"+keyword+"\\b.*");
                                               ^
System.out.println(matches);
```

Comment: sorry, I made the mistake while posting the question. But In my code those things are proper. Kindly guide me on using boundaries.

Comment: did you replace `var` with `para` ?

Comment: Yes,. It is just a dummy example to show what I did

Answer (score 0):

If I replace `var` by `para` and fix the quotes in line 3, `matches()` returns true:

```
@Test
public void testName() throws Exception
{
    String para = "Hi how are you. I'm harshita. Hello. Hell. Helld, Hell,";
    String keyword = "Hell";
    boolean matches = para.matches(".*\\b"+keyword+"\\b.*");
    logger.debug(matches); 
}
```

Output:

```
08:52:18.059 [main] temp.temp - true
```

Comment: It runs fine in my local system, but not in the unix server. there it is giving the error.